# Error creating user:Error occurred while executing NewUser Code:Authorization_RequestDenied Message:Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-automation, azure-runbook, identity-management

I need your help I am trying to manage identity provisioning on azure automation for this I am automating the process of adding a user to Azure AD using an azure automation runbook and a system managed identity knowing that the account and identity are General Administrators but this is not working and is showing me this error which I cannot resolve. Please help me to solve this problem. Here is my powershell code and the error :
The error:
Error creating user: Error occurred while executing NewUser
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
RequestId: 34be9739-4e8a-47f1-b5b3-fa2adb042d8e
DateTimeStamp: Thu, 13 Apr 2023 09:15:30 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed

The code:

Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$DisplayName,

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$UserPrincipalName,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$MailNickName,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$UsageLocation,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$Department,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$ConnectionName
```

)

try{

```
# Connect to Azure with the system-assigned managed identity
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context



Import-Module AzureAD
#Connect-AzureAD
$azureContext = Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$azureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $azureContext.context.Subscription -DefaultProfile $azureContext.context
$graphToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
$aadToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.windows.net"
Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $azureContext.account.id -TenantId $azureContext.tenant.id -AadAccessToken $aadToken.token -MsAccessToken $graphToken.token    

$PasswordProfile = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$PasswordProfile.Password = "MotDePasse123!"
$PasswordProfile.ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = $false
$User = New-AzureADUser -AccountEnabled $true `
    -DisplayName $DisplayName `
    -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName `
    -MailNickName $MailNickName `
    -UsageLocation "US" `
    -Department $Department `
    -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile


Write-Output "User $UserPrincipalName created successfully."
```

} catch {
Write-Output "Error creating user: $_"
}

I am using an azure automation runbook with a managed identity to create a new user in azure ad knowing that both have a general administrator role

---

I tried adding the owner role to the system-managed identity but it didn't solve the problem.I have the same problem of authorization.
[Add the owner role to the system-managed identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUhxI.png)

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the managed identity doesn’t have sufficient roles to perform the action.

To create a new user  **`Administrator role`**  is required. Make sure to assign the role.

After assigning the role, I am able to create a new user like below:

```c
#Connect to Azure with the system-assigned managed identity
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context

Import-Module AzureAD
#Connect-AzureAD
$azureContext = Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$azureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $azureContext.context.Subscription -DefaultProfile $azureContext.context
$graphToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
$aadToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.windows.net"
Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $azureContext.account.id -TenantId $azureContext.tenant.id -AadAccessToken $aadToken.token -MsAccessToken $graphToken.token    

$PasswordProfile = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$PasswordProfile.Password = "MotDePasse123!"
$PasswordProfile.ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = $false
$User = New-AzureADUser -AccountEnabled $true `
    -DisplayName $DisplayName `
    -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName `
    -MailNickName $MailNickName `
    -UsageLocation "US" `
    -Department $Department `
    -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile


Write-Output "User $UserPrincipalName created successfully."
```

[image]

In the Portal,  **user got created successfully**  like below:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much,but how can i assign Administrator role to a system-assigned managed identity,I tried that but it doesn't work Connect-AzAccount $identity = Get-AzADServicePrincipal New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $identity.Id -RoleDefinitionName "Owner" Disconnect-AzAccount

Comment: Kindly check this reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal-managed-identity

Comment: I have tried to add the role of ower to the identity but it doesn't work and i got the same error. i used this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal-managed-identity